# Show whole data in query

Tags: oracle

I want to show all data if there is no value in where condition. A date will be there. However, for other parameters, sometimes there can be no value.

Condition

WHERE (DATE = :date or :date is null)
AND (CHANNEL_PARTNER IN (:channel_partner) or :channel_partner is null)
AND (CURRENT_BUCKET IN (:current_bucket) or :current_bucket is null)

If there are multiple values in the current bucket then getting the syntax error like - AND (CURRENT_BUCKET IN ('1','2') or ('1','2') is null). Here after OR condition --> or ('1','2') is null getting the syntax error. Please guide

Comment: why don't just take away other condition if you are not gonna include them in your query...

Comment: It's important to include then as well sometimes user needs to see the whole date then no parameters value needs to be mention. Or what sort of data user wants they enter the value

Comment: nope, you cant just have a condition and ignored it, either create a function with dynamic query or take it away. and what do you mean sometimes user need? you let user directly access your database and write the query? arn't you got some frontend?

Comment: This where condition using in a parameterized pipeline function, by sometimes user need means if the user wants to see the data for the East zone then in a dropdown East option gets selected and data will be of East zone and of that particular date that user has selected..And if no parameter value is there then only data of a particular date will be there , because date field is mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you are passing the values from your application.

You can get the desired result using some `OR` conditions as follows:

```
WHERE (DATE = :date or :date is null) 
  AND (CHANNEL_PARTNER IN (:channel_partner) or :channel_partner is null)
  AND (CURRENT_BUCKET IN (:current_bucket) or :current_bucket is null)
```

Comment: @Popeye...this is working fine, however, if there are multiple current buckets then getting the syntax error. If the code comes in this way ; (current_bucket in('1','2') or ('1','2') is null). So here in this condition --> OR ('1','2') is null getting an syntax error. If you can guide how to remove that please do let me know.